# Design Pattern for returning a credit card base on a boolean

Tags: java, design-patterns

I wrote a GUI for users to input his/her credit card number. The program must return the correct Credit Card class subclass such as MasterCard, Visa, etc.

Here is my code:

```
abstract class CreditCard{

    String cardNumber;

    public CreditCard(String number) {
        cardNumber = number;
    }
}
```

All of my subclass such as MasterCard, Visa, etc extends the CreditCard superclass.

Example of one of my subclass:

```
class MasterCC extends CreditCard {

    public MasterCC(String number) {
        super(number);
    }
}
```

I chose a Factory Design Pattern

```
class CreditCardFactory {

    static CreditCard createCard(String number) {
        CreditCard cc = null;

        if (number.length() == 0 || number.length() > 19)
            return cc;
        else if (isMasterCard(number))
            cc = new MasterCC(number);
        else if (isVisa(number))
            cc = new VisaCC(number);
        else if (isAmericanExpress(number))
            cc = new AmExCC(number);
        else if (isDiscover(number))
            cc = new DiscoverCC(number);
        return cc;
    }

    private static boolean isMasterCard(String number){

        if (number.length() != 16)
            return false;
        return (number.charAt(0) == '5' 
            && 1 >= Integer.valueOf(number.charAt(1)) 
            && Integer.valueOf(number.charAt(1)) <= 5);
    }
    // more code boolean code
}
```

My professor said to redo it because it isn't a good design pattern to solve it. She said the responsibility should not be the job of the factory but of the subclasses.

My solution:

```
class CreditCardFactory {


     public static CreditCard createCard(String number){
            CreditCard cc[] = { new AmExCC(number), new VisaCC(number)};

             for(int index=0; index<cc.length; index++)
                    if(cc[index].isMyType())
                         return cc[index];

     return null;
}
```

}

Comment: He did not offer any suggestion, just "redo it" ...?

Comment: It was a she. She said the responsibility of verifying which subclass should be the subclass's responsibility.

Comment: maybe she is suggesting a static method that check those criterias ex: MasterCard.CheckType() to proof if the card is master or not

Comment: @JohnLe that doesn't really make sense because how do you know which subclass to ask when the question itself is "Which subclass am I instantiating". Chicken and the egg issue...

Comment: You should ask your professor how she wants it done specifically since it's her criticism. There are all kinds of ways this could be done and there is not necessarily a "best" way.

Comment: What she's saying is you may want to have in your abstract CreditCard an abstract method isCardType() which returns a boolean. That should do all of the validation for that given card type. And then if you really wanted to get fancy schmancy, you could use reflection to find all child classes for that abstract parent in a given package, iterate the list, and instantiate a child when the type matches.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view you only have to move those boolean methods to the concrete classes. The factory method might then look similar to this:

```
static CreditCard createCard(final String number) {

    if (MasterCC.isValidNumber(number)) {
        return new MasterCC(number);
    }

    if (VisaCC.isValidNumber(number)) {
        return new VisaCC(number);
    }

    if (AmExCC.isValidNumber(number)) {
        return new AmExCC(number);
    }

    if (DiscoverCC.isValidNumber(number)) {
        return new DiscoverCC(number);
    }

    return null;
}
```